# Finding the numbers that are non-attainable and partitioning.

Tags: number-theory

I have been working through some past math competition problems and have had difficulty in solving some of the ones on number theory. Examples include:

1) If we need 27 cents can we make it using 5 cents and 8 cents?

2) Given $1. How many ways can you make it from 20 cents, 10 cents and 5 cent coins?

3) How may ways are there of making 4 (using addition) with numbers (non-negative) less than 4?

4) What is the highest non-attainable number when adding numbers from 6,9 and 20?

I was able to solve these problems with the use of trial and error however, this seemed highly inefficient due to the great number of such questions in the competitions. So, I was wondering whether there is a formula that would allow me to quickly solve them.

Help would be appreciated,
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Here are two different answers of number 2). Both of them could be interesting when looking for a systematic approach. The first one provides a more general approach, the second one is presumably more efficient when fast calculation is needed.

In both cases it is helpful to observe that finding solutions in non-negative integers of 
\begin{align*}
5p+10q+20r=100
\end{align*}
is equivalent to finding solutions of non-negative integers of
\begin{align*}
p+2q+4r=20
\end{align*}

So, in the following we are looking for the number of partitions of $20$ with elements from $\{1,2,4\}$.

> **First approach: Generating Functions**
>
> We develop a formula for the number of partitions of $n$ with elements from $\{1,2,4\}$. Question $2$ is answered by applying the formula to $n=20$. Zero or more $1$'s can be algebraically described as
>
> \begin{align*}
> z^0+z^1+z^2+z^3+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   with the power of $z$ in (1) indicating the number of $1$'s. Zero or more $2$'s can be algebraically described as 
>   \begin{align*}
> z^0+z^2+z^4+z^6+\cdots\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>    with the power of $z$ in (2) indicating the number of used $2$'s in the partition.
>
> The number of partitions of $n$ with elements from $\{1,2,4\}$ can thereby described as the coefficients of $z^n$ in the *generating function* $F(z)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> F(z)&=\left(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots\right)\left(1+z^2+z^4+z^6+\cdots\right)\left(1+z^4+z^8+z^{12}+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^4}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+z}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-iz}\cdot\frac{1}{1+iz}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-iz}\cdot\frac{1}{1+iz}
> \end{align*}

The coefficient of $z^n$ of the generating function $F(z)$ contains the information of the number of wanted partitions. The following calculation is more or less straightforward. We use *[partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)* of $F(z)$ and develop each term as power series and finally extract the coefficient of $z^n$.

> Using partial fraction decomposition we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> F(z)&=\frac{9}{32}\frac{1}{1-z}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}+\frac{5}{32}\frac{1}{1+z}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}+\frac{1-i}{16}\frac{1}{1-iz}+\frac{1+i}{16}\frac{1}{1+iz}\\
> &=\frac{9}{32}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{k}(-z)^k
> +\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-3}{k}(-z)^k+\frac{5}{32}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^k\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{k}z^k+\frac{1-i}{16}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(iz)^k
> +\frac{1+i}{16}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-iz)^k\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

Since $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$ we observe
\begin{align*}
\binom{-2}{k}&=\binom{k+1}{k}(-1)^k=(-1)^k(k+1)\\
\binom{-3}{k}&=\binom{k+2}{k}(-1)^k=(-1)^k\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2}
\end{align*}

In the following we use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient $a_n$ in $A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$.
$$[z^n]A(z)=[z^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k=a_n$$

> Now we are ready to extract the coefficient of $[z^n]$ from the generating function $F(z)$ in (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n]F(z)&=\frac{9}{32}+\frac{1}{4}\binom{-2}{n}(-1)^n+\frac{1}{8}\binom{-3}{n}(-1)^n+\frac{5}{32}(-1)^n\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{16}\binom{-2}{n}+\frac{1-i}{16}i^n+\frac{1+i}{16}(-i)^n\\
> &=\frac{9}{32}+\frac{1}{4}(n+1)+\frac{1}{16}(n+2)(n+1)+\frac{5}{32}(-1)^n\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{16}(-1)^n(n+1)+\frac{1-i}{16}i^n+\frac{1+i}{16}(-i)^n\\
> &=\ldots\\
> &=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{16}\left(n^2+6n+7-2(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)\qquad \qquad& n \text{ odd}\\
> \frac{1}{16}\left(n^2+8n+14+2(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)\qquad \qquad& n \text{ even}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> Finally we obtain for $n=20$
>   $$[z^{20}]F(z)=\frac{1}{16}\left(20^2+8\cdot 20+14+2(-1)^{\frac{20}{2}}\right)=\frac{576}{16}=36$$

$$$$

> **Second approach: Iteratively from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,2,4\}$**
>
> This is an elementary approach by first obtaining a formula $a_n$ which contains the number of partitions with elements from $\{1,2\}$. Once we have found $a_n$ we use it as basis to find a formula for the number of partitions with elements of the extended set $\{1,2,4\}$.
>
> In order to find $a_n$ we use the *Ansatz*:
>   $$n=2p+r\qquad\qquad r=0,1$$
>   We see that $n-r=2p$ is even and the number of possible summands $2$ of a partition of $n=2p+r$ is $0,1,2,\ldots,p$. Therefore we obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n=p+1=\frac{n-r}{2}+1=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1
> \end{align*}
>   We observe
>   \begin{align*}
> r=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad n\text{ odd}\\
> 0&\qquad n\text{ even}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   So, $r=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}$
>   and we obtain this way the number $a_n$ of partitions of $n$ containing elements from $\{1,2\}$
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n&=\frac{n-r}{2}+1=\frac{2n+3+(-1)^n}{4}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   In order to determine the number $c_n$ equal the number of partitions of the extended set $\{1,2,4\}$ we use a similar approach as before. We start with
>   $$n=4p+r\qquad\qquad r=0,1,2,3$$
>   We get
>   \begin{align*}
> c_n=a_n+a_{n-4}+a_{n-8}+\ldots+a_{n-4p}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>   Setting $n=20$ we obtain using formula $a_n$ of (4)
>   \begin{align*}
> c_{20}&=a_{20}+a_{16}+a_{12}+a_8+a_4+a_0\\
> &=\frac{44}{4}+\frac{36}{4}+\frac{28}{4}+\frac{20}{4}+\frac{12}{4}+\frac{4}{4}\\
> &=11+9+7+5+3+1\\
> &=36
> \end{align*}

*Note:* We calculated $c_n$ without deriving a closed formula for it. But, we could also derive one from
$$c_n=\sum_{j=0}^{p}a_{n-4j}$$
and the formula for $a_n$ of (4) by considering the different values of $r=0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, see the artilce on the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). You will need the notion of a gcd and other tools from elementary number theory. 
The third question is answered by the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function). We have $p(4)=5$. If you want the summands less than $4$, then we have
\begin{align*}
4 & = 1+1+1+1,\\
  & =1+1+2,\\
  & =1+3,\\
  & = 2+2.
\end{align*}
There is a general formula for $p(n)$ and an asymptotic formula, namely
$$
p(n) \sim \frac {1} {4n\sqrt3} \exp\left({\pi \sqrt {\frac{2n}{3}}}\right) \mbox { as } n\rightarrow \infty. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Begin with an intuitive approach: 27 Plus 8 equals 35 35 is a multiple of 5. 27 times 8 ends in five, which is also a multiple of 5. The purpose of turning over numbers is to help the mind to see alternatives. Then you can understand what lies beneath  equations.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental question at work here is "what is the (typed) value of unity".  Each of the solution results in $Z$ units of some $\Omega$ "coin" which is valued at $\pi$, the same as the original coins. I use $\alpha_n$ to denote the value of the original coins and $x_n$ to denote the number of coins.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Omega &=& \left(\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \frac{\alpha_nx_n}{Z}\right) + \frac{\alpha_k\left(Z-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}x_n\right)}{Z} && \\
 &=&  \alpha_k - \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} (\alpha_k-\alpha_n)x_n}{Z}\\
\frac{1}{Z} &=&  \frac{\alpha_k - \Omega}{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} (\alpha_k-\alpha_n)x_n}\\
Z &=& \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} x_n + \frac{\pi-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \alpha_nx_n}{\alpha_k} \\
\Omega Z &= \pi
\end{eqnarray}
$$

A good starting point is to note that $Z * \frac{1}{Z} = 1 $

#### Exercise 1

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Omega &=& 5a/Z + 8(Z-a)/Z && \\
 &=&  8 - \frac{3a}{Z}\\
\frac{1}{Z} &=&  \frac{8 - \Omega}{3a}\\
Z &=& a + (27-5a)/8 \\
\Omega Z &=& 27\\
1 <= &\Omega& <= 27 &&\\
0<=&a&<= 5 &&\\
0<=&Z-a&<= 3 &&\\
1<=&Z&<= 8 &&
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Here the key is to use modulo arithmetic to solve for $Z = a + b$.  I start with $Z * \frac{1}{Z} = 1 $ and simplify to get:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{8 - \Omega}{3a}\frac{8a + 27-5a}{8} &=& 1 \\
  (8 - \Omega)(3a + 27) &=& 24a \\
  (24 - 3\Omega)a-24a &=& 27(8 -\Omega) \\
  (27-3a)\Omega &=& 216 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

#### Exercise 2

The trick here is to partition the problem:

$$
\Omega_k =  \frac{Z_1\Omega_1+\alpha_k\left(Z_k-Z_1\right)}{Z_k} 
$$

#### Exercise 3

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Omega &=& a/Z + 2b/Z + 3(Z-(a+b))/Z && \\
 &=&  3 - \frac{2a + b}{Z}\\
\frac{1}{Z} &=&  \frac{3 - \Omega}{2a + b}\\
Z &=& a + b + (4-a-2b)/3 \\
\Omega Z &=& 4\\
1 <= &\Omega& < 4 &&\\
0<=&a&<= 4 &&\\
0<=&b&<= 2 &&\\
a+b+c-Z&=&0 \\
1<=&Z&<= 4 &&
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Here the key is that $\Omega Z = 4$, with $Z \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ so $\Omega \in \{4.0, 2.0, 1.\overline{3},1.0 \}$, taking into account the constraints each choice of $Z$ places on $a, b, \text{ and } c$.

#### Exercise 4

I'm not sure that this question belongs in the same category.  The question requires two numbers $a$ and $b$, one odd  and one even.  Assuming $b>a$, if the gcd of the numbers is 1, then a sequence of length $b+1$ exists made from expressions starting at $a*(b)+b*(0)$ and ending at $a*(0)+b*(q)$, where $0\le q \le a$ is chosen to keep the sum between $a*(b-1)+1$ and $a*b$. Each value must be unique, so this makes the extreme upper limit $a*(b-1)-1$.  If $a*(b-1)-1 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } b$, then the value is $a*(b-2)-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the following answers are non-formulaic. Luckily, they are one-liners.

1. If we need $27¢$, can we make it using $5¢$ and $8¢$ coins?

The $8¢$ pieces must number from $0$ to $3$, so the second digit must be $\{0,8,6,4,5,3,1,9\}$ which is not $7$, so no.

2. How many ways can you make $\$1$ from $20¢$, $10¢$ and $5¢$ coins?

Because of the regular intervals of the coins, this is a path problem where `O` = $20¢$, `X` = $10¢$ and `V` = $5¢$:

```
$0                     $1.00
| O   O   O   O   O    |
| X X X X X X X X X X  |
| VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV |
```

Order does not matter, so moves are either right or down. Because one cannot always exit the top row, assume that there are only $n = 5$ junctions and multiply by 2 for the extra options on the bottom row. There is 1 path terminating on the top row, $\binom{n}{1} = n$ paths terminating on the middle row, and $2 \cdot \binom{n+1}{2} = n(n+1)$ terminating on the bottom row. $f(n) = 1 + 2 n + n^2 = (n+1)^2$, so $f(5) = 36$

From the bottom row up, there are $n = 10$ junctions, so rather than an undercount which may be multiplied into compliance, the overcount, $\binom{n/2}{n/2-2} = \dfrac{n}{2} \left(\dfrac{n}{2}-1\right)$, must be subtracted yielding $f(n) =1 + n + \left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)^2$ for even $n$.

3. How may ways are there of making 4 (using addition) with numbers (non-negative) less than 4?

As both positive rationals and irrationals have infinite ways to add to 4, I'm assuming natural numbers:
Simplest approach: $1+1+1+1 = 2+1+1 = 2+2 = 3+1 = 4$; 4 ways.

4. What is the highest non-attainable number when adding numbers from 6,9 and 20?

Given some natural number $n$, $2 \cdot 6 = 12$ and $9+6 = 15$, so every $6 + 3n$ is attainable. Similarly, $26 + 3n$ and $46 + 3n$ are attainable. The highest unattainable number is $43$.